# Portion of particle bar greyed out in timeline, makes particles behave abnormally

Tags: animation, particles, timeline

I'm not sure what I did to cause this, but the bar at the bottom was all red and now a section of it is greyed out. the animation behaves normally when it's in the red part but as soon as the playhead reaches the greyed-out section it's like half the particles suddenly stop and say still while the other half moves really fast. is this a glitch? Exiting and re-entering the program makes it behave normally again.[image: a screenshot of the greyed out area]

Answer (score 0):

The red line is the simulation data that is cached for these frames. The different simulations in Blender have different colors and caches. For a particle simulation it's red, for cloth it's blue, for softbody is also red, Explosion is orange, and so on.

When you change the settings of the physics simulation, the cache is normally cleared. Then, when the simulation runs, the line fills up and the data is stored for another run. But when you start the simulation in the middle or scrub the timeline, then the data for the previous frames are missing or there can be gaps.

Sometimes, updating the cache doesn't work properly for these gaps and the simulation goes wonky. But you can refresh the cache manually:

- make sure the simulation starts at frame 1
- or make a dummy change in the settings to force a refresh
- or if this doesn't help, bake the cache. This calculates the simulation data and saves it in the memory (or to disk if enabled) until you free the cache again. You cannot change the settings until you free the cache/delete the bake.

Also, make sure the length of the cache is correct. Like the timeline, most physics caches have a start and an end frame. (Particles don't have these settings).